# Driving to Dubai from Muscat. Which border is better?

Tags: driving, borders, gcc

I'm driving to Dubai from Muscat and there are two options for border crossing. One is Al Ain and the other is Hatta. Al Ain has a longer route, but I heard that non-GCC nationals can't go through Hatta. Is that true?

Comment: What travel documents do you have?

Comment: OP hasn't clarified, putting on hold for now.